# Semantic Zoom Like UWP People App

Tags: c#, uwp

I am developing UWP app. I want to implement Semantic Zoom in my app. I have a collection of grouped data and it is sorted alphabetically. I want to represent my group title in ZoomOut view like Windows 10's People app represents. Here is a picture that will help you to understand my concept.

[image: Semantic Zoom]

1. How can I do like this ?
2. How can I prevent users from clicking on D, J, K, L items (as I
   don't have any items of D, J, K, L in ZoomInView) of GridView.

Here is a sample that I have built. I need further help to implement advanced Semantic Zoom.

[Semantic Zoom Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Semantic-Zoom-Sample-13f54e41?redir=0)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I do like this ?

If you want to sort your group title by alphabetic from A ~ Z.

You just need to sort your groups before your bind it to your ListView's ItemsSource.

```
var gpData = Contacts.GroupBy(a => a.Name[0], (key, con) => new GroupData() { HeaderTitle = key, Items = con.ToList() }).OrderBy(o=>o.HeaderTitle);
```

> How can I prevent users from clicking on D, J, K, L items (as I don't have any items of D, J, K, L in ZoomInView) of GridView.

The basic principle is that you need to set the `IsEnabled` property of ListViewItem to false.

```
<SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind CVS.View.CollectionGroups}" SelectionMode="None" GotFocus="ListView_GotFocus">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="wuxdata:ICollectionViewGroup">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Group.(data:GroupData.HeaderTitle)}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
</SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
```

For your case, you would need to set the `IsEnable` property dynamically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur respond